# Container approach to building multiple frames is not working

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

Im trying to make a GUI using tkinter which allows to add, delete and update a database. I wanted to use [the approach mentioned here on switching between frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter/7557028#7557028) to create the frame. However I added my own interface with buttons, labels etc. I'm not getting the GUI I want, instead I get a blank tkinter window. (Some of the comments are just notes for me) Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.
Code is as follows:

```
import sqlite3

class mainclass(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        self.frames = {}

        #pack the dictionary of frames into the container
        #for F in (maindatabasegui):
        frame = maindatabasegui(container, self)
        self.frames[maindatabasegui] = frame
        frame.grid(row = 0,column = 1,sticky = 'nsew')

        #calling upon another class
        self.show_frame(maindatabasegui)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class maindatabasegui(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.geometry("500x500")



        #list of labels to be made
        self.labels = [('fnamelabel',2,'First Name'),('lnamelabel',4,'Last Name'), \
                       ('addresslabel',6,'Address'),('citylabel',8,'City'),\
                       ('joblabel',10,'Occupation')]
        #list of entry to be made
        self.entrys = [('fnamelabel',2),('lnamelabel',4), \
                       ('addresslabel',6),('citylabel',8),\
                       ('joblabel',10)]

        for group in self.labels:
            self.labelmaker(group[0],group[2],group[1])

        for group in self.entrys:
            self.entrymaker(group[0],group[1])

        #variable for dropdown menu
        self.selectedrecord = tk.StringVar()

        self.addbutton = tk.Button(self, padx = 10, pady = 10, width = 30, relief = 'raised', command = lambda: self.addrecord())
        self.addbutton.config(text = 'Add Record')
        self.addbutton.grid(row = 12, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

        self.viewbutton = tk.Button(self, padx = 10, pady = 10, width = 30, relief = 'raised',command = lambda:self.viewrecord())
        self.viewbutton.config(text = 'View Record')
        self.viewbutton.grid(row = 14, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

        self.deletebutton = tk.Button(self,padx = 10,  pady = 10, width = 30, relief = 'raised', command = lambda: self.deleterecord())
        self.deletebutton.config(text = 'Delete Record')
        self.deletebutton.grid(row = 16, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

        #self.editbutton = tk.Button(self,padx = 10, pady = 10, width = 30, relief = 'raised', command = lambda)

        self.statuslabel = tk.Label(self,  padx = 10, pady = 10, width = 30, relief = 'raised')
        self.statuslabel.grid(row = 18, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

        #list is not specified initially(notice that you can just mention the variable, without the default and list of options)
        self.addedrecords =  tk.OptionMenu(self, self.selectedrecord,self.selectedrecord.set('Select Record'),())
        self.addedrecords.grid(row = 2, column = 3, padx = 10)

        #message widget
        self.viewspace = tk.Message(self,text = 'Record Details',relief = 'sunken') 
        self.viewspace.grid(row = 4, column = 3, padx = 10)            
        #SQL Section
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('addressbookdb.sqlite')
        self.curs = self.conn.cursor()

        self.curs.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Addresses (
            id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
            first_name TEXT,
            last_name TEXT, 
            address TEXT,
            city TEXT, 
            job TEXT)''')

        rows = self.curs.execute('''SELECT first_name, last_name FROM Addresses''')
        if rows is not None:
            menu = self.addedrecords['menu']
            menu.delete(0,'end')
            for row in rows:
                #row is a tuple
                name = row[0] + ' ' + row[1]
                menu.add_command(label = name , command = lambda value = name: self.selectedrecord.set(value))



        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()


     #instead of repeating the code, create a list with tuples
     #and assigned the string attribute name with the object
     #these attributes still belong to the self object
    def labelmaker(self,labelname,textval, rowpos):
        setattr(self,labelname,tk.Label(self, text = textval,anchor = 'w',width = 10))
        getattr(self,labelname).grid(row = rowpos, column = 1, pady = 10, padx = 10)

    def entrymaker(self,entryname,rowpos):
        setattr(self, entryname,tk.Entry(self,width = 20, borderwidth = 5))
        getattr(self,entryname).grid(row = rowpos, column = 2, pady = 10, padx = 10)

    def addrecord(self):
        #gets all the fields from the entry boxes
        firstname = self.fnamelabel.get()
        lastname = self.lnamelabel.get()
        address = self.addresslabel.get()
        city = self.citylabel.get()
        job = self.joblabel.get()

        #creates a list of all the entries and checks if any are empty
        comparelist = [firstname, lastname, address, city, job]
        pos = [i for i, f in enumerate(comparelist) if len(f) < 1]

        #adds data if all fields are not empty
        #else tells user
        if len(pos) > 0 :
            self.statuslabel.grid_forget()
            self.statuslabel.config(text = 'Please fill in all the required fields')
            self.statuslabel.grid(row = 18, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
        else:
            #this is only used to collect the names to be added
            name = str(firstname) + ' ' + str(lastname)

            #dynamically adding the records into the dropdown menu
            menu = self.addedrecords['menu']
            menu.add_command(label = name, command = lambda value = name: self.selectedrecord.set(value))

            #SQL section    
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect('addressbookdb.sqlite')
            self.curs = self.conn.cursor()

            self.curs.execute('''INSERT INTO Addresses 
                              (first_name, last_name, address,city,job) 
                              VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)''',(firstname,lastname,address,city,job))
            self.statuslabel.grid_forget()
            self.statuslabel.config(text = 'Record Loaded')
            self.statuslabel.grid(row = 18, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

            self.conn.commit()
            self.conn.close()

    def deleterecord(self):

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('addressbookdb.sqlite')
        self.curs = self.conn.cursor()
        self.curs.execute('''DELETE FROM Addresses WHERE 
                              first_name = ? AND last_name = ?''',(self.selectedrecord.get().split()[0],self.selectedrecord.get().split()[1]))

        menu = self.addedrecords['menu']
        menu.delete(self.selectedrecord.get())
        self.selectedrecord.set('Select Record')

        self.statuslabel.grid_forget()
        self.statuslabel.config(text = 'Record Deleted')
        self.statuslabel.grid(row = 18, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

        self.viewspace.config(text = 'Record Details')
        #clearing the view space after deleting

    def viewrecord(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('addressbookdb.sqlite')
        self.curs = self.conn.cursor()
        row = self.curs.execute('''SELECT * FROM Addresses WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?''',(self.selectedrecord.get().split()[0],self.selectedrecord.get().split()[1]))

        element = row.fetchone()

        self.viewspace.config(text = 'Record Details: \n ID = {} \n First Name = {} \n Last Name = {} \n Address = {} \n City = {} \n Occupation = {}'.format(\
                              element[0],element[1],element[2],element[3],element[4],element[5]))

        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

#class EditPage()










root = mainclass()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container itself is has to be placed in the main window.

```
class mainclass(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()
        ...
```